# MSN Protocol Documentation

Tags: msn, msn-messenger, windows-live-messenger, windows-live

Does anyone know of a good (up-to-date) reference for the MSN protocol? I have found some sites with simple google searches, but they all seem pretty dated. Does anyone know of a good source of documentation that they can vouch for... that they have used recently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this wiki.

http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/wiki/KB_MSNP21